# Uploading a file in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, file-io

I'm new to rails, and I'm writing a RESTful website using the CRUD technique. So far I have created three pages, all of which allow the user to create, edit, and delete a row from the database. However, my fourth page will need to include an upload file form, but a) I don't know how the filesystem works with Rails thus I don't know where files should be stored. The file would be around 100kb and couldn't be stored in temporary storage because it will be constantly downloaded. And b) I don't know how to write to a file.

It would be great if you could tell me how to do what I mentioned above - create an upload input on an input form, and to then write the file to a filepath in a separate directory.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

**Update 2018**

While everything written below still holds true, Rails 5.2 now includes `active_storage`, which allows stuff like uploading directly to S3 (or other cloud storage services), image transformations, etc. You should check out the [rails guide](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html) and decide for yourself what fits your needs.

---

While there are plenty of gems that solve file uploading pretty nicely (see https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_file_uploads for a list), rails has built-in helpers which make it easy to roll your own solution.

Use the `file_field`-form helper in your form, and rails handles the uploading for you:

```
<%= form_for @person do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :picture %>
<% end %>
```

You will have access in the controller to the uploaded file as follows:

```
uploaded_io = params[:person][:picture]
File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', uploaded_io.original_filename), 'wb') do |file|
  file.write(uploaded_io.read)
end
```

It depends on the complexity of what you want to achieve, but this is totally sufficient for easy file uploading/downloading tasks. This example is taken from the rails guides, you can go there for further information: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files

Comment: I don't want to write the file to the database though, just the filepath, won't the code you provided write it to active-record?

Comment: no, actually the code writes it just to the filesystem, and not to the database at all. In fact, you still need to associate the file with your database record somehow (e.g. by setting the filename of the uploaded file to the id of the record). You can look up the ruby documentation for more information on `File.open` ( http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-open ).

Comment: Please edit the code to use `wb` instead of just `w`, or upload may fail for files with non ascii chars.

Comment: What is in the `new` controller method?

Comment: I don't understand this answer. What should be name of action where I should paste the code from the second listing? What route does the form from the first listing send the picture on? Where is it said?

Comment: @KarolSelak this example just provides the general outline for simple file uploads, you can learn more about routing and forms in the rails guides (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html /  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#dealing-with-model-objects)

Comment: thank you for updating your answer 5 years later. @fabi

Answer (score 8):

**Sept 2018**

For anyone checking this question recently, [Rails 5.2+ now has ActiveStorage by default & I highly recommend checking it out.](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html)

Since it is part of the core Rails 5.2+ now, it is very well integrated & has excellent capabilities out of the box (still all other well-known gems like Carrierwave, Shrine, paperclip,... are great but this one offers very good features that we can consider for any new Rails project)

Paperclip team deprecated the gem in favor of the Rails ActiveStorage.

[Here is the github page for the ActiveStorage](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activestorage) & plenty of resources are available everywhere

[Also I found this video](https://gorails.com/episodes/file-uploading-with-activestorage-rails-5-2) to be very helpful to understand the features of Activestorage

Answer (score 3):

There is a nice gem especially for uploading files : [carrierwave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave). If the wiki does not help , there is a [nice RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads) about the best way to use it . Summarizing , there is a field type `file` in Rails forms , which invokes the file upload dialog. You can use it , but the 'magic' is done by `carrierwave` gem .

I don't know what do you mean with "how to write to a file" , but I hope this is a nice start.

Comment: I see , so you are OK with tis gem .

Answer (score 0):

Okay. If you do not want to store the file in database and store in the application, like assets (custom folder), you can define non-db instance variable defined by attr_accessor: document and use `form_for - f.file_field` to get the file,

In controller,

```
 @person = Person.new(person_params)
```

Here `person_params` return whitelisted `params[:person]` (define yourself)

Save file as,

```
dir = "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/custom_path"
FileUtils.mkdir(dir) unless File.directory? dir
document = @person.document.document_file_name # check document uploaded params
File.copy_stream(@font.document, "#{dir}/#{document}")
```

Note, Add this path in `.gitignore` & if you want to use this file again add this path `asset_path`an  of application by `application.rb`

Whenever form read file field, it get  store in tmp folder, later you can store at your place, I gave example to store at assets

**note**: Storing files like this will increase the size of the application, better to store in the database using `paperclip`.

Answer (score 0):

In your intiallizer/carrierwave.rb

```
if Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.test?
    config.storage = :file
    config.root = "#{Rails.root}/public"
    if Rails.env.test?
      CarrierWave.configure do |config|
        config.storage = :file
        config.enable_processing = false
      end
    end
 end
```

use this to store in a file while running on local