# File upload to S3 from Rails returns no implicit conversion of Hash into String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload a file through a form to AWS S3. Here is my controller right now:

```
    s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new(access_key_id: AWS_CREDS[aws_env]['access_key_id'], secret_access_key: AWS_CREDS[aws_env]['secret_access_key'], region: "us-east-1")
    resource = Aws::S3::Resource.new(client: s3)
    obj = resource.bucket('mybucket').object(file_name)
    obj.upload_file(file: params[:upload_file], acl: :private)
```

This returns a `no implicit conversion of Hash into String` error. This looks correct based on what I'm seeing in other examples so I'm not sure where I went wrong.

How do I access the file that was uploaded? `p params[:upload_file]` just returns the filename, I do not see a hash. Do I need to do further processing on the file before I am able to upload it?

Form:

```
= form_tag(form_path, :method => "POST", enctype: 'multipart/form-data') do

    %input{:name => "authenticity_token", :type => "hidden", :value => form_authenticity_token}
    .form-group
        .col-sm-3
            %label Document name or date
            = text_field_tag('name', nil, class: 'form-control')
            - if @errors and @errors['name']
                %span{:class => "form-error"}
                    = @errors['name']
        .col-sm-3
            %label Document type
            = select_tag('type', options_for_select(['1', '1'], ['2', '2']), class: 'form-control')


        .col-sm-3
            %label Select file
            = file_field_tag 'upload_file'
            - if @errors and @errors['upload_file']
                %span{:class => "form-error"}
                    = @errors['upload_file']

        .col-sm-3
            %br
            %input.btn.btn-primary.btn-sm{:type => "submit"}
```

Comment: Which is the line that raises the error?

Comment: `obj.upload_file(file: params[:upload_file], acl: :private)` is the line raising the error.

Answer (score 0):

**First**, you didn't tell us what `params[:upload_file]` is but if you're attempting to upload a file through a form and pass it along to the AWS upload via the params object it won't work. You have to give `upload_file` a path to the file you want to upload, that means it has to be on same filesystem as your Rails server. If you're currently in a development environment this may unintentionally work for you since it's on your local machine, but it will fail on a production server.

**Second**, you said want to access the file that was uploaded but `p params[:upload_file]` is printing filename? `params[:upload_file]` is the input, it won't contain any information about the uploaded file. If you want to access a successfully uploaded file you need to look at the url on the `obj`. Try calling `obj.public_url`. Of course, you will need to set `acl: :private` to `acl:'public-read'`.

Take a look at [this example](https://ruby.awsblog.com/post/Tx1K43Z7KXHM5D5/Uploading-Files-to-Amazon-S3), it might help you.

EDIT:

`params[:upload_file]` is a **not** the uploaded file. It is `StringIO`? object, you have to finish the uploading job in the controller. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14174249/1241782) will help you properly do file uploads. Once you have successfully uploaded a file via Rails, you can take the path of that new file and pass it to the AWS upload.

I **strongly** advise not trying to get the Rails form file upload AND the AWS upload working in one giant sweep. Get one working, then the other. You can test AWS upload by reading my original answer and instead of trying to pass your `params[:upload_file]`, just pass a string path to a known file on your local machine. For example, put a test text file in your /tmp directory, then pass that path `/tmp/test_file` to your `upload_file` call.

Comment: My code above is based on that example however where they get their file differs from my situation. I will update my question with the form as well which I believe is what you are asking for.

I am asking how I access a file once it has been passed from a form to the controller.

Comment: I've seen that example but `params[:file].original_filename` is deprecated and was giving me issues. Also `params[:file].read` returns a no method error.

Comment: @apardes okay so that SO answer my be for a different version of Rails. But the general point is still the same. `params[:upload_file]` isn't literally the uploaded file. You need to get file uploading via Rails working first, then move on to the second issue with AWS.

Comment: Or use a file uploading gem like Paperclip (recommended) or Carrierwave, they do a lot of work for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to save the file before you upload that to S3 Bucket.
Once you're in controller, your file is already stored in a temp directory.
So, to upload the file to S3 on AWS-SDK v 2.x you can do:

```
obj = S3_BUCKET.object('file_name')
obj.upload_file(File.expand_path(params[:file].tempfile))
```

Posting your file named 'file', controller will store that automatically in a temp folder.

```
params[:file].tempfile
```

Is a reference to a temporary file, and we need to get the PATH to the file by:

```
File.expand_path(params[:file].tempfile)
```

That is it ;)