# How to Upload files in Ruby on Rails by passing API to it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

Bellow Image is a sample post request that I would like to send in my Ruby on Rails Server, with a parameter of item_id(contains an ID) and a file(contains the file.). But I do not know how to process it in the rails controller.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. We're not here to replace official documentation or tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

Import `HttpClientModule` from `@angular/common/http`.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';
import { UploadService } from './upload.service';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpClientModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [UploadService]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then use `HttpClient` to make the request.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
@Injectable()
export class UploadService {

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
  ) { }

  upload(itemId: string, file: File) {
    const form = new FormData();
    form.append('item_id', itemId);
    form.append('file', file)
    return this.http.post('http://example.com/url', form);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I already know how to to this, I am trying to accept in the back end. Do you know how to accept file using ruby on rails with mondoid?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Rails.

Comment: please delete your answer, im going to take down my question because its not accepting any answers anymore.

Comment: The top answer on this post provides a simple example of the controller action to accept an attached file and write it to disk. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14174044/uploading-a-file-in-rails