# Reading uploaded data on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, post, upload, pcap

I am using a rails server to receive data from an application.
A simple POST Request receiver is implemented as follow :

```
  #POST /pcap_uploads/curl
  def curl
    filename||= "#{SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64}.pcap"
    tempfile = Tempfile.new(filename)
    tempfile.binmode
    tempfile << request.body.read
    tempfile.rewind
    data_params = params.slice(:filename).merge(:tempfile => tempfile)
    data = ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.new(data_params)
    File.open(File.join(Rails.root, "/public/uploads/" << filename), 'w+b') { |f| 
        data.rewind
        while  !data.eof?
          f.write(data.read)
        end
    }
    respond_to do |format|
        format.json { head :ok }
    end
  end
```

My problem is that the data written contains my binary file (pcap format) surrounded by POST Request information such as :

```
--------------------------5625702e57f980bd
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="capture.pcap"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

<binaryfile content>
--------------------------5625702e57f980bd--
```

I can't find a way to delete these lines without altering my content.
Does someone have an idea of what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Check in `params` (use `puts params.inspect`to print it) if the file is present. Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11342338/how-to-upload-a-file-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: Please check documentation http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files and "5.1 What Gets Uploaded" section

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload a file in ruby on rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11342338/how-to-upload-a-file-in-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I could simply use the :file parameter from *params*.

```
      #POST /pcap_uploads/curl
  def curl
    filename||= "#{SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64}.pcap"
    #Rails.logger.debug params.inspect
    #puts params[:file].inspect
    data = params[:file]
    t=  data.tempfile
    File.open(File.join(Rails.root, "/public/uploads/" << filename), 'w+b') { |f| 
        t.rewind
        while  !t.eof?
          f.write(t.read)
        end
    }
    respond_to do |format|
        format.json { head :ok }
    end
   end
```

Thanks to [Baldrick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1128103/baldrick) for debug tips.

Answer (score 0):

I just leave an example of handling of file uploading from [official Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files)

```
def upload
  uploaded_io = params[:person][:picture]
  File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', uploaded_io.original_filename), 'wb') do |file|
    file.write(uploaded_io.read)
  end
end
```