# getting encoding error cannot convert ascii-8bit to utf-8bit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using this code for uploading the profile image of a user

```
if params[:user][:image].present?
  uploaded_io = params[:user][:image]
  name = "image_" << @user.username << uploaded_io.original_filename
  File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'images','profile',name ), 'w') do |file|
    file.write(uploaded_io.read)
  end
end
```

but its giving this error when i run it `cannot convert ascii-8bit to utf-8bit`
so what i did was i changed my default encoding in `application.rb` file like this `config.encoding = "ascii-8bit"` from `config.encoding = "utf-8"`. and it started working fine.

But the problem is now I am sending a mail to the user for successful registeration from simple rails mailer and now before sending the mail its giving me this error `cannot convert utf-8bit to ascii-8bit`.

Now I am totally struck only one of them works at one time. I have tried a lot of suggested solutions to `enforce_encoding on strings` but none of them seems to work. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @ajt yeah the solutions suggest to change the mysql to mysql2 but i don have any error while saving in database its while writing to the image file. so I am still struck. thanks for the link btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changed 'w' to 'wb'

```
if params[:user][:image].present?
  uploaded_io = params[:user][:image]
  name = "image_" << @user.username << uploaded_io.original_filename
  File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'images','profile',name ), 'wb') do |file|
    file.write(uploaded_io.read)
  end
end
```

Comment: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988724/ruby-on-rails-upload-file-problem-odd-utf8-conversion-error