# How to get the filename of uploaded file in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload

```
<%= file_field 'upload' %>
```

In my controller, if I give the following, based on suggestions

```
filename=params[:upload]
@result=filename.original_filename
```

I am getting.

```
undefined method `original_filename' for 
#<ActionController::Parameters:0x002b6c396e44b8>
```

Note: I am not using form. 
Rails version is 4.0.2

Comment: Are you sure, the file is being uploaded to the server? I am asking this because you are not using `form` to perform file upload.

Comment: @Rohit based on your suggestion I have included form. file is getting uploaded . But I want to get the file name alone

Comment: `filename.original_filename`

Comment: @Nithin this is what am getting undefined method `original_filename' for #<ActionController::Parameters:0x002b6c396e44b8>

Comment: @user94962 [file upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988724/ruby-on-rails-upload-file-problem-odd-utf8-conversion-error/4988984#4988984)  followed it and implemented it, just last week

Comment: uploaded_file.file.filename will give you humanized name of file

Answer (score 6):

Use the following code in order to get the filename:

```
params[:file].original_filename
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you read how to [upload files in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files)?  Have you set your form to `multipart: true`?  What will be in the `params` is either a `StringIO` or a `File` (depending on the size of the upload).  On that object, you will have an `original_filename` attribute, which is the filename of the uploaded file.

edit: I see you said you aren't using a form to submit...  What alternative steps have you taken to make that work in general?

Comment: How to use this original_filename attribute ?

Comment: Call it on the object in the params, just like in the example linked above: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files

Comment: When I tried like that, this is what am getting 
`undefined method `original_filename' for       #<ActionController::Parameters:0x002ad2b8148b78>`

Comment: If you're calling `original_filename` on `params`, that won't work.  You need to call it on the object *in* `params`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add permit for :upload params

```
def some_params
   params.require(:something).permit(:upload)
end
```

[Refer on rails document]
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Oh, I got it now, I am fresh on this so I did not know about reputation. I only wanted to help. I will get experience. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
params[:pictures][0]["picture_path"].original_filename.split(".").first
```