# Display file contents from the given Rails DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am able to display the contents a specific file using: `<%= render file: "#{Rails.root}/filepath", layout: false %>`, however, I need to access each file from the database dynamically and acquire its file path.

In the `index.html.erb` view file, I `link_to articles_path`, which is this route `article GET - /articles/:id(.:format) - articles#show`. Meaning the show URL ends in articles/:id. I am able to display the file title and id by using the instance variable @article.title and @article.id. Additionally, I can get a download link by using `<%= link_to "View File", @article.file%>`, here is the example link (when I inspect the page) to download the file within the show view page  `<a href="/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBCZz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--045b71b4dec3d3bfe6cec88145761e50106c0922/test2.txt">View File</a>`. However, I do not want to download the file, just display contents (text) on the webpage. How can I access the file path dynamically?

I have tried using `@filename = params[:file].original_filename` (in the show method in article_controller) because of this stack overflow question: [How to get the filename of uploaded file in rails contoller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21979570/how-to-get-the-filename-of-uploaded-file-in-rails-contoller). I do not think it works.

I also tried `<%= cdata_section(File.read(@filename)) %>` ( int the `view/show.html.erb` file), but I am getting an undefined error: undefined method 'original_filename' for nil:NilClass

Code:

```
#application_record.rb
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end

#article.rb
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :file
end

#articles_controller.rb
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end
  
  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end
  
  def new
  end
  
  def create
    @article = Article.new(params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text, :file)) 
    @article.save

    redirect_to @article
  end
  
  def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.destroy

    redirect_to articles_path
  end
  
  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text, :file)
  end
end
```

I believe the files are being stored in active storage blobs in the local Rails DB. Here is my `config/storage.yml`; we are storing the files locally, so the files are in a hierarchy in the storage directory under the root of my app

```
#config/storage.yml
test:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>

local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>
```

Comment: What is `params[:file]` though?  Can you give an example of what that show URL looks like because usually that is just an `id` getting sent but you are trying to call it like the file is the params.  you likely (without seeing it) need to get the file using the `id` and then add in the path depending on how it is being stored.  how are the files being stored?  Is this just locally you need to solve this or in an app being hosted somewhere, if so where are the files actually being hosted?

Comment: @RockwellRice, I made changes to my post that address your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Rendering contents, via a link, is not an option for a full stack page. You will either have to use an xhr request (an ajax request) to fetch the contents, or link to a view that renders the contents of the file.

Assuming you want to keep things simple, then, there are a couple of things to do.

The naming is conventional, adjust to your liking.

Create a route to your view:

```
#config/routes.rb
get '/filecontents/:id', to: "articles#read"
```

Then, create an action to render the view

```
#app/controllers/articles_controller.rb
def read
    @article = Article.find params[:id]
    path = method_to_get_your_path_from_article #this is your job
    @text = File.open(path).read # get the contents in a variable
end
```

Now, assuming your file has a text file structure, all you have to do is create a minimal view:

```
#views/articles/read.html.erb
<pre><%= @text %></pre>
```

This should simply get you going. You will have to enhance it, of course.

Oh, don't forget to set the `link_to` to show to the route you just created

Comment: I appreciate your help. Unfortunately, I am not sure what I am supposed to put for the path variable. I don't know how to correctly get the file path. I tried searching through the routes using `rake routes` in the terminal. I noticed, by adding the code you suggested `get '/filecontents/:id', to: "articles#read"`,  `GET - /filecontents/:id(.:format) - articles#read` was added to the list of routes. However, since there is no prefix (before GET), I am not sure what to call. Is this the correct method of getting the file path?